# How to get last occurence of a word using regex and, then, match what follows

Tags: regex

in this exemple below

`[{"id":"ABW","iso2Code":"AW","name":"Aruba","region":{"id":"LCN","value":"Latin America & Caribbean "},"adminregion":{"id":"","value":""},"incomeLevel":{"id":"HIC","value":"High income"},"lendingType":{"id":"LNX","value":"Not classified"},"capitalCity":"Oranjestad","longitude":"-70.0167","latitude":"12.5167"},{"id":"AFG","iso2Code":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"`

I would like to match the id of a country, depending on its name.
For exemple, if i want to find the id of Afghanistan, i would like to get AFG.
I tried that :

```
id":"([A-Z]+).*?name":"Afghanistan
```

but it gives me the first occurence of ID (ABW), not the one just before Afghanistan.
How can i do ?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Because regex engines parses the string from left to right. When it finds the first `id":"` it starts matching and `.*?` finds all up to the first `name":"Afghanistan`. You  should not use a regex to parse JSON, use a dedicated library.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew,  ok i will do that. Still, i would like to find the answer ;) So, how you i tell the regex to match the last occurence of id before Afghanistan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`"id":"([^"]*)"[^}]*"Afghanistan"`](https://regex101.com/r/dEv9U7/2)

The first captured group will be the id.

- `"id":"` Literal text
- `([^"]*)` Capture group 1. Includes any number of non-`"` characters
- `"` Literal text
- `[^}]*` Any number of non-`}` characters. This will make sure it doesn't go beyond the current JSON object.
- `"Afghanistan"` Literal text

Comment: Thank's so much ! It helps me a lot